# Using Lists in Windows Phone

Tags: c#

For some reason only my last item is being added to my list. How do I ensure each clinic gets added to the list?

```
List<Clinics> _clinics = new List<Clinics>();
Clinics _newClinic = new Clinics();

_newClinic._id = "1";
_newClinic._Name = "Test Clinic 1";
_newClinic._Phone = "(121) 123 348";

_clinics.Add(_newClinic);
         
_newClinic._id = "2";
_newClinic._Name = "Test Clinic 2";
_newClinic._Phone = "(121) 123 348";

_clinics.Add(_newClinic);
_newClinic._id = "3";
_newClinic._Name = "Test Clinic 3";
_newClinic._Phone = "(121) 123 348";

_clinics.Add(_newClinic);

MyMap.AddPushpin(new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 51.5, Longitude = -0.05 }, "1");
    MyMap.AddPushpin(new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 51.503399, Longitude = -0.119519 }, "2");
    MyMap.AddPushpin(new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 51.5057, Longitude = -0.1419 }, "3");

    searchList.ItemsSource= _clinics.ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

You need to create a new instance of `Clinics`, in your case you are just updating the existing instance in your List.

```
_clinics.Add(new Clinics() { _id = "3", /*etc*/ });
```

---

What you have is:

```
List<Clinics> _clinics = new List<Clinics>();
Clinics _newClinic = new Clinics();
_newClinic._id = "1";
_newClinic._Name = "Test Clinic 1";
_newClinic._Phone = "(121) 123 348";
```

So far so good, there is a list with this first one in.

```
_clinics.Add(_newClinic);
```

Now you are adding the same clinic again - **ID 1**.
The list has 2 items both the same.

```
_newClinic._id = "2";
_newClinic._Name = "Test Clinic 2";
_newClinic._Phone = "(121) 123 348";
```

Now the instance in the list (twice) is been **updated** to the details of clinic **ID 2**.

There is only 1 instance of `_newClinic` and a list that contains it twice.

And so on...

As I said at the start, you need to create a new instance for each clinic.

---

Also, the C# convention is to expose properties from your type with PascalCase naming.

```
class Clinic //Singular?
{
    private string _id; //maybe int?
    public string Id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
}
```

There are plenty of articles on line about the advantages of encapsulating fields with properties.

Comment: as said this is just mocking code just a quick demo for customer more thoru in release

Answer (score 1):

You are updating fields of the very same object every time. To get the behavior you really need, make sure to create a new object after you added the previous one:

```
_clinics.Add(_newClinic);

_newClinic = new Clinics();
_newClinic._id = ...
```

As a side note, consider renaming you class `Clinics` to `Clinic`, as it really represents just a single clinic object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as stated only updates _newClinic object. You need to create new object each time you want new object to be added. You could use List initialization for that:

```
List<Clinics> _clinics = new List<Clinics>
{
     new Clinic { _id = 1, _Name = "Test Clinic 1", _Phone = "(121) 123 348" }, 
     new Clinic { _id = 2, _Name = "Test Clinic 2", _Phone = "(121) 123 348" },  
     new Clinic { _id = 3, _Name = "Test Clinic 3", _Phone = "(121) 123 348" }
};
```